Postman / newman - repeat request until response will return proper value
Problem: When testing my API the logic is that a task is being locked. During this time backend is doing some calculations (I don't have control over it). When finished - an endpoint will return: isLocked: false, otherwise is returning all the time isLocked: true.
I need to stop collection requests execution until task is no longer locked and I am using it few times within same collection.
My solution: I have created a custom function to handle such scenario which works in most of cases, but in some of them is not working - meaning postman / newman will wait until task is no longer locked, but then will skip next (subsequent) request which obviously will fail the tests.


const responseJson = pm.response.json();

function checkIfTaskIsUnlocked(responseJson) {
    if (responseJson.items && responseJson.items[taskId]) {
        if (responseJson.items[taskId].isLocked === false) {
              return true;
        } else {
            console.log('Task is still locked');
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Task ID not found in the response JSON');
        return false;
    }
}



if (!checkIfTaskIsUnlocked(responseJson)) {
    console.log('Retrying the request in 10 seconds...');

    setTimeout(function() {
        pm.execution.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName);
    }, 10000);



My solution result:  In most cases it works as expected, but for some requests not anymore. For some cases it waits for the task to be unlocked, but then continues collection execution by skipping next subsequent request - meaning my test run will fail.
Why is this happening - some special async in postman logic?
How to prevent / control this with simple, reusable code?
Timeout (wait) between sending requests is a must have for me.
